# Unable to install voip app in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, voip

I am getting below error on running my app on iPhone 6. I am trying to implement VoIP feature.

[image]

What is the solution for this ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I am using below code for VoIP feature.

```
func application( _ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data ) {



      let voipRegistry =  PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
      voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
     voipRegistry.delegate = self;
```

}

```
extension AppDelegate : PKPushRegistryDelegate {
  func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
    NSLog("PusRegistry didUpdateCredential....")
    let deviceTokenString: String = pushCredentials.token.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    NSLog("PushCredentials: \(deviceTokenString)" )

    UIPasteboard.general.string = deviceTokenString

 showLocalNotifiacation(text: "Received pushCredential")

    NSLog("Token is : \(deviceTokenString)")
}


 func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, 
       didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType) {
}

func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
    NSLog("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>><><><><><><><>><><>><><><><><")
    NSLog("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>><><><><><><><>><><>><><><><><")
    NSLog("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>><><><><><><><>><><>><><><><><")
    NSLog("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>><><><><><><><>><><>><><><><><")
    NSLog("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>><><><><><><><>><><>><><><><><")
    NSLog("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>><><><><><><><>><><>><><><><><")
    NSLog("<**************** Syncing data because of VOIP ***************")
     sharedSilentPushSyncManager.syncDataForOperation("Syncing... for voip")
     showLocalNotifiacation(text: "Received voip push")
}
```

}

Comment: what is your effort?

Comment: I am trying to run the app using xcode.

Comment: did you registered your device for that profile?

Comment: Yes device is  registered.

Comment: @AashishNagar did you enable VoIP push notifications, remote notifications on your membership account app id ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one!

1.Open your Xcode.
2.Go to your project **target**.
3.Click **Capabilities** tab in target.
4.Check with the following screenshot and enable **Push Notification**, **Background Modes** capabilities.
[image]

[image]

5.check your **info.plist** of your project.

[image]

6.Check your settings provided with above information and correct it.

Thank you!